# AWSCognitoIdentityUser getSession not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, authentication

I'm trying to get the idToken from an AWSCognitoIdentityUser however the continue block is never called. What could be the cause of this?

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];
AWSCognitoIdentityUser *user = [pool currentUser];

[[user getSession] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession *> * _Nonnull task) {
    //Never called
    return nil;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

First turn on verbose logging: `[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;`
That will usually help determine what the error is.

Sounds like you have associated a [AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Protocols/AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate.html#//api/name/startPasswordAuthentication) with your pool.

Is the startPasswordAuthentication method getting called?  Is it correctly returning a implementation of [AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Protocols/AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication.html) and are you setting passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource.result to an instance of [AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails.html) in your implementation of [getPasswordAuthenticationDetails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Protocols/AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication.html#//api/name/getPasswordAuthenticationDetails:passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource:)